# props getting added twice to the array variable that is declared outside the component in React / Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to add, new data that user enters, to the array declared outside the component named DUMMY_MEALS and then render it as a list.

The problem here is the 'data' which is an object adds twice or more to the DUMMY_MEALS and renders twice in the page. [image]Why is this happening?

The component with issue

```
"use strict";
import React from "react";

let DUMMY_MEALS = [
  {id: "m1", name: "Sushi"},
];

const MealList = ({data}) => {
  //const data = {id: "m5", name: "pushi"}

  let mealslist = [];
  DUMMY_MEALS = [data, ...DUMMY_MEALS];
  mealslist = DUMMY_MEALS.map((meal) => <li>{meal.name}</li>);

  return <ul>{mealslist}</ul>;
};

export default MealList;
```

Parent component

```
const Header = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    const sendInputData = (inputData) => {
        setData(inputData);
    }

    return (
        <>
          <MealsList data={data}/>
          <MealForm getInputData={sendInputData}/>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Sibling Component

```
const MealForm = (props) => {

    const [name, setName] =useState("");

    const formSubmitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let inputData = {
            key : Math.random(),
            name : name,
        }
        props.getInputData(inputData);
        inputData = {};
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
            <label htmlFor="name">name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}></input>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default MealForm;
```

Comment: Can you show the sample of what's in `data`?

Comment: We won't be able to help you with your problem by looking at a screenshot, it looks like you're adding data via a form but you haven't posted anything from that component. Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BrendanBond I have added the parent component. Please check.

Comment: @raina77ow I have added log throughout the steps, you can see that in the above screenshot.

Comment: As I mentioned, you're adding data using the `<MealForm>` component. You still haven't posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BrendanBond Sorry, its my first post. I have added all the related components with its basic code that reproduce the issue.

Comment: (a) Make it "minimal" please. Remove every line of code that is not necessary to reproduce the bug. That reduces the barrier to readers trying to help you, because it will be less for them to read and discard.

(b) Can you get it into the `<>` icon that allows it to execute directly in the browser? Those sorts of questions get quicker solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useState` hook instead of `let mealslist = [];` Inside your `MealList` component.

And don't use DUMMY_MEALS as the component state. use `useEffect` hook to add the new meal to the state just once.

Check out this tested code [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-black-cpl7i?file=/src/MealList.js)

MealList component changed as follow :

```
const MealList = ({ data }) => {  
const [mealslist, setMealList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (data) 
    setMealList([data, ...DUMMY_MEALS]);    
}, []);    

return <ul>{    
  mealslist.map((meal)=>{ <ListRender meal={meal} />})
}
</ul>;

};
```

And here is your `App` component:

```
const data = {
    id: "k123",
    name: "Falafel",
    description: "An Iranian food.",
    price: 16.5
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MealList data={data} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. It will work.
But, I am trying to understand why it doesn't work with DUMMY_MEALS variable, that's the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @MIDHUNV because DUMMY_MEALS is a regular variable outside the component and because the component render twice, the props will be added twice to the DUMMY_MEALS. on the other hand if you trying to use 'useEffect' in order to prevent dubble values, you cannot see the changes because DUMMY_MEALS is not a 'state'. Please see the CodeSandbox I prepared for you.

Comment: Ok. I had put console.log at each step. If component is rendering twice, doesn't it console multiple times? That didn't happen

Comment: I tried yours, It works that way. But here, as you can see above, I have made the code leaner, The form data from "MealForm" control the state of its parent component "Header". "MealList" component is its child. When I add a state variable in "MealList", it is going on an infinite loop.